# Unable to update a specific spreadsheet row using API

Tags: google-sheets-api

I tried to update a spreadsheet row as given [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#updating_a_list_row) Protocol tab. 
Few Questions:
How do I get gd:etag? None of my workbook requests or /full requests contains info about eTag.
So I tried to send a PUT request without etag and getting an error message "Unexpected resource version ID". 
Can some one point me where am doing wrong?

Comment: Got it! Somehow i forgot to add GData version in HTTP headers. Adding v 3.0 in headers solved the issue!!

Comment: Can you post your full PUT request?  I'm having the same problems and would like to see your working answer.